# Frequency Domain - Meaning

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-domain

I'm new in digital signal processing and having hard time understanding this. By Fourier Transform I mean Discrete Fourier Transform as it's the only one I'm learning.

As far as I know Fourier Transform transforms a signal into an equivalent set of signals in sinusoid form, which when summed gives the original signal back.

If I got it right, a signal could also be represented by other things instead of sinusoids but because sinusoids are easy to process this is preferred and FT is used.

I also understand that with DFT I get amplitude and phase of the sinusoid at given frequency. But why should I care about these properties(amplitude, phase and frequency) of equivalent sinusoids? What's so special about it and does it really have a "natural" meaning?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! I don't know if this answers the question and it might be off-topic, but I think [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY) is great.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  Please read the question and its answers that I've marked as a duplicate of your question. If you don't think it's a duplicate, please [edit your question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/54812/edit) to make it clearer what the differences are between the duplicate and your question.